# Lost http request

Tags: java, android, http

I am writing an android application, and use the following line of code in my application,

```
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I have verified through the debugger, that neither the httpClient, nor the httpPost are null.
Yet sometimes, even in the presence of a wifi connection, the above line does execute, but the server is not hit. What could be the cause of this problem?

Moreover, weirdly, there are three such calls in my code. The first two work, the last one dose not. However, **if I replace the second call, with a dummy call to google, then the third call works!**

Regards

Comment: Also, does android send and http request only from the UI Thread?

Comment: @KumarBibek No errors in logcat.

Comment: please post full code with the logcat.

Comment: Sounds like timeout trouble, is this through a router or data connection?

Comment: @Merlin it is through a router.

Comment: @Merlin Also, we have set the timeout to infinite in the application. However, the server is not even hit when the third call is sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a HTTP request from a background thread too, in fact best practice is to do so as you don't want to wait for a response on the UI thread.

If you get no error messages - and you're not handling it with a do-nothing catch clause, then the problem is either in the server's code not showing you the request, or in the network. If it's a remote server, you may have a problem with a proxy or firewall. You could do some packet capturing with tcpdump, wireshark for Android. Or route your traffic through a PC to see network activity on a larger screen.

Comment: How may I "route traffic through a PC" ?